# It there a library or web service that would provide daylight saving data to my javascript application?

Tags: javascript, time, timezone, browser

***What I want to do***: Implement a localizable clock in javascript. The idea is that the user would select a town, and the clock would display current local time, taking into account daylight saving data.

***Question***: Is there a reliable web service, or alternatively a library that I should update from time to time that would provides the two things listed below ?

- A set of named locations.
- A process that gives me the timezone and the daylight saving data for a given location.

Note: This is meant to be in a gadget where I have no server-side support, so I need a pure javascript solution or a public web service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- pure JavaScript solution: [timezone-js](https://github.com/mde/timezone-js)
- public web-service http://www.earthtools.org/webservices.htm#timezone